# Looping through 2 lists in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have 2 lists, I need to iterate them and duplicates to be removed from the main list.
Ex:

```
ListA = {
    [25151, "China DC", "Mar 14, 2014"], [8171, "Singapore IMT", "Mar 14, 2014"]
}
ListB = {
    Object {
        id = 3, dcName = "Argentina DC", countrycode = 613
    }, Object {
        id = 101, dcName = "ASEAN", country = "ASEAN"
    }, Object {
        id = 2, dcName = "Brazil DC", countrycode = 631
    }, Object {
        id = 6, dcName = "Central Europe", countrycode = 668
    }, Object {
        id = 5, dcName = "China DC", countrycode = 672
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < ListB.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < listA.length; j++) {
        if (listA[j][1] == ListB[i].dcName) {

        } else {

            htmlStr += dcList[i].dcName;

        }
    }
}
```

the output should be such that

> China DC
>   Singapore IMT
>   Argentina DC
>   ASEAN
>   Brazil DC

and so on...

But now what the output I get is,
the duplicates of all DC;s twice.
how to loop it in script.pls help

Comment: Consider editing your question to your exact code or maybe a fiddle. Provided sample is not a valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I would use underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org) which will provide the _.uniq function (removes the duplicates of an array) as well as several other convenient function for your problem.

Probably what you need is something like:

```
// get all the DC values
var allDC = [];
for (var key in ListB)
{
allDC.push(ListB[dcName]);
}
// remove duplicates
allDC = _.uniq(allDC);
// remove the values from the first list
for (key in ListA)
{
ListA[key] = _.filter(ListA[key], function(object){ return _.indexOf(object,allDC) === -1; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to push all the data and check its `.indexOf`

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ListB.length; i++) {
    if (data.indexOf(ListB[i].dcName) == -1){
        data.push(ListB[i].dcName);
    }
}

for (var j = 0; j < ListA.length; j++) {
    if (data.indexOf(ListA[j][1]) == -1){
        data.push(ListA[j][2]);
    }
}

alert(data);
```

And you shoud also define your multi-array (ListA) in this way:

```
var ListA = [[25151, "China DC", "Mar 14, 2014"], [8171, "Singapore IMT", "Mar 14, 2014"]];
```

And also your JSON format (ListB) in ths way:

```
var ListB = 
   [{
     id: 3, dcName: "Argentina DC", countrycode : 613
    }, 
    {
        id : 101, dcName : "ASEAN", countrycode : 123
    },  
    {
        id : 2, dcName : "Brazil DC", countrycode : 631
    }, 
    {
        id : 6, dcName : "Central Europe", countrycode : 668
    }, 
    {
        id : 5, dcName : "China DC", countrycode : 672
    }];
```

check out [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/396BE/14/) here